# 'Dependency not found' with release 17 while analyzing

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin, java-17

One of [the project](https://github.com/mrwilson/java-8-matchers) that I was looking into has these relevant configurations:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>analyze-only</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <!-- not scoped to test -->
</dependency>
```

On executing `mvn clean verify` (apache-maven-3.6.3, java : 17-ea), the build succeeds as expected. I have now, made a change in the properties to **replace**  the source and target with release as:

```
<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
```

and the logs on the terminal read

> ```
> [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:analyze-only (default) @ java-8-matchers ---
> [WARNING] Non-test scoped test only dependencies found:
> [WARNING]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:compile
> ```

leading to a failure(because of warning)! Why/How is the dependency treated differently with the upgrade in the Java version? Any way to fix this?

---

If it might be of help, the debug logs for this goal reads:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:analyze-only from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@579bb367]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:analyze-only' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) analyzer = default
[DEBUG]   (f) baseDir = .../java-8-matchers
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnWarning = true
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreNonCompile = false
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreUnusedRuntime = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = .../java-8-matchers/target
[DEBUG]   (f) outputXML = false
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: uk.co.probablyfine:java-8-matchers:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ .../java-8-matchers/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) scriptableFlag = $$%%%
[DEBUG]   (f) scriptableOutput = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[WARNING] Non-test scoped test only dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:compile

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:analyze-only (default) on project java-8-matchers: Dependency problems found -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:analyze-only (default) on project java-8-matchers: Dependency problems found
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
```

Reproduce using:

1. Git checkout [this branch](https://github.com/namannigam/java-8-matchers/tree/modular-artifact).
2. Configure maven to use Java-17.
3. Edit the `failOnWarning` property to `true`.
4. Execute `mvn clean verify`.

Comment: @BasilBourque I have replaced the previous two properties with the release one.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @BasilBourque, have made an edit to make that explicit and share a link to complete project to attempt reproducing.

Comment: Did you try replacing the `17` with `1.8` to narrow down whether the hamcrest issue is due to Java 17 or due to the use of `release`?

Comment: That shouldn't be a concern for the configuration of `maven-dependency-plugin` or any other for that matter. But yeah, to be very sure, I have tested that as well @BasilBourque and it fails as otherwise. My hunch is the issue might be hidden in the "How" part of my question.

Comment: Randomly trying out things, for one,`<scope>provided</scope>` helps the build succeed. But usage of the library is impacted as `org.hamcrest.Matcher` is no more accessible after that or one would get *Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.hamcrest not found, required by uk.co.probablyfine.matchers*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After investigation I figured out that issue is in upgrading `maven-dependency-plugin` from version 3.1.2 to 3.2.0, because in new version of plugin was added new property for analyzing:  `testArtifactsWithNonTestScope` you can compare screenshots of code below:
Version 3.1.2:

[image]

Version 3.2.0:
[image]

I debugged the full analyzer dependencies process in the plugin and found that dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
   <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

is passed to `testArtifactsWithNonTestScope` set of artifacts because class `org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert` is used only in test classes. Of course that behavior is incorrect, because other classes from `hamcrest` dependecy are present in non test classes - definitely there is defect in `maven-dependency-plugin`.

**P.S.**

Like proof of my idea you can change one of non test classes in following way:

```
...
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
...

public final class Java8Matchers {

    public static void customAssert(String reason, boolean assertion) {
        assertThat(reason, assertion);
    }
    
    ...
}
```

**As you can see I added new method with usage of `org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert` in `Java8Matchers` and after that build process will be finished successfully.**

---

**After all the above aspects, you have the following ways to solve the issue:**

- use the latest version of java which is supported by plugin 3.1.2 and do not update the plugin until the bug is fixed
- turn off the analyzer for the build and wait for the fix for the analyzer

Comment: This makes sense, have created [MDEP-759](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-759) corresponding to this question with a comment mentioning your first-hand debugging. Thank you for investing your time.

Comment: One quick question, with the concept, that `3.2.0` brings in the issue we are discussing, should the failure not reflect with Java-8 as well there?

Comment: It doesn't matter which version of java, there is bug in plugin starts from 3.2.0 version

Comment: Yeah, I could revalidate that. I agree it's the upgraded version. Should be a critical bug in my opinion, since this is breaking backward incompatibility. Thank you for your findings as well. Updating the bug reported too.

Comment: Have awarded the bounty for the useful findings which confirms that it's a bug. Would wait for a certain response to see, what could be a better solution than just using `MatcherAssert...` unnecessarily in a non-test class.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with OpenJDK 11.0.11.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to the Java version, it also fails with Java 16, to me it seems that it appeared when the maven-dependency-plugin was upgraded from 3.1.2 to 3.2.0 by dependabot, downgrading solves the problem.

Comment: Using the mentioned version of the plugin results in `Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:analyze-only failed: Unsupported class file major version 61`. The problem is related to upgrading the java version as the configurations work just fine with `3.2.0` and `Java-8`.

Comment: Yes unfortunately this version of the plugin will fail with versions above Java 15.

Comment: The configuration doesn't work with **3.2.0** and **Java-8** on my computer either.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason I had tagged the question with the Java version I am working with.

Comment: To redress what I had said, you were right that the issue is with `3.2.0`. The details are shared in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68171467/1746118).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by cloning the maven-dependency-plugin from the following repo https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/tree/maven-dependency-plugin-3.2.0 and I built it myself. Then I used the 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT version in my project!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31131054)

Comment: The issue is on the maven-dependency plugin. The maintainers said they have fixed it in version 3.3.0 but it is not released yet. The problem is caused by the code that identifies Non-test scoped test-only dependencies. It is not working correctly so to solve the problem I cloned the dependency repository and commented out the code that gives the above warning. This is the edited repo https://github.com/Haylemicheal/maven-dependency-plugin. However, When the maven-dependency-plugin-3.3.0 is released you should use that dependency.